# extract csfr token from json with python

Tags: python, json, authentication, request, token

I need to extract _csrf_token value from json below with python:

```
json_string='{
"success":true,
"suggestedResponseStatus":200,
"message":null,
"registration"::"null",
"login":{
   "title":"form.login.label",
   "type":"object",
   "properties":"null",
   "defaultValue":{
      "_csrf_token":"6JmkBsyuZHvKuipUev_mqqBajarmqNyfrhUlXp2G6z0"
   },
   "action":"\/it\/profile\/login"
 }
}'
```

I have tried with the following funziona, but doesn't works for the json in subset

```
json_obj = json.loads(json_string)
print(json_obj["success"]['defaultValue']["_csrf_token"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Your object is nested, so you need to do this:

`json_obj["properties"]["_csrf_token"]`

In other words, dictionaries can contain other dictionaries, and your object has a dictionary called `properties` that has 2 other dictionaries - `email` and `_csrv_token`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, ok I undstrand that there are 2 other dictionaries. For printing defaultValue of _csrf_token how can I do ? I have  tried this; `json_obj = json.loads(json_string)
  print(json_obj["properties"]["_csrf_token"]["defaultValue"])`

Comment: `print(json_obj["login"]['defaultValue']["_csrf_token"])`